# Открытие файла Манифест, как увидеть код

Tags: android-manifest

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Открываю проект и вместо кода вижу то что на скрине, что делать?

```
      X                (   4   \   t   �   �   �   �   �     $  6  ^  x  �  �  �  �  �  �      2  P  j  �  �  �  �    @  Z  r  �  �  �    J  l  �  �  �  �    "  ,  <  F  h  �  �    "  P  r  �  �  D  �  �  �    "  J  ^  ~  �  �        n   �   $
```

�

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в данном случае лучше картинкой )

Comment: См. [статью о реверс-инжиниринге APK файлов](https://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/reverse-engineering.php)